# Python: FFT parallel computing

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, mpi, fft

I have a cluster of few PC's with Ubuntu and MPICH server - I use them to parallel computing with C++ and MPI. Now I want to do similar with Python. My question is - is there any easy method to make Fast Fourier Transform on many CPU cores (on many computers)? Example of usage would be nice. Here is method I use on single thread:

```
import numpy as np
N=1024
tab=np.random.rand(N,N,N) #declare some matrix in 3d
a=np.random.rand(N,N,N) #declare other matrix
tab=np.fft.ifftn(a*np.fft.fftn(tab))
```

It's nice to have multithreaded solution when we have 2^30 numbers...

Answer (score 1):

[MPI4py](http://pythonhosted.org/mpi4py/) in connection with [pyFFTW](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyFFTW).  FFTW is highly optimized and works well on multiple threads but the interface is a little different than your average FFT as it requires creating 'plans' outright.  However, this was just done to optimize out processing of any static twiddle factors and such.  Additionally, there are lots of options - forward/reverse, in/out-of-place, int, double, float, etc...  See [benchmarks](http://www.fftw.org/speed/Pentium4-3.60GHz-icc/) for more info.

Comment: Sooo... how would you code it? I was looking on Stack for an example to work with, I wrote only because I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [thread](https://github.com/hgomersall/pyFFTW/issues/38) which discusses the development of MPI python with pyFFTW. From this it seems like [pfft](https://github.com/rainwoodman/pfft-python) may be a better solution and the minimal example python code is given at https://github.com/rainwoodman/pfft-python/blob/master/example.py.